# Equalization two complicated objects in java (two objects that are made from other object)

Tags: java, object, memory, point

Let's say you have this piece of code in java:
Contact is made from name and number, and PhoneBook from an array of Contacts.

//set -> Does this method really copies and creating new memory place or just pointing to the memory?

```
public void setContact(Contact[] contact)
{
    this.contact =  contact; // <----this
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are objects, and object references are passed by value in Java. So calling this method makes `this.contact` be a copy of the reference to the contact array passed as argument. No copy of the array elements is made. No copy of the array is made.

Comment: so this method is useless, and I have to use copy constructor method?

Comment: Why would it be useless? Making a copy of the array could be more appropriate, but it depends on the context. Making a copy of each contact in the array could also be more appropriate, but it depends even more on the context. For example, if Contact is an immutable class, making a copy doesn't make sense. I would avoid arrays anyway, and use collections instead.

Comment: I haven't learned collections yet. 
Anyway, thanks for the answer.
But let me check again: 
if I use this method and change this.contact again consequently contact will be change afterwards because they are pointing to the same memory?

Comment: Yes, whatever change you make will be reflected on both variables since they refer to the same array.

Answer (score 0):

By using this you are setting a reference to the the object which is in heap from your stack
i.e your object is in heap and your reference is in the stack

By using new keyword only you get new object which acquires space in heap